# Authentication - JavaScript - Logout issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need some help with my problem.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
    console.log('log in');
    window.location.href ='event_list.html'
    }});

btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        console.log("not log in");
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }, function(error) {
    //
    });;

});
```

Logging in works correctly but if I'm trying logout - user probably logout correctly - back to login/signup site but immediately I'm redirecting to "event_list.html" as still logged in user.

My sign in/sign up site is - index.html

I want logout and put other data - login/pass.

One other question: How can I get email variable from this script and use it in other JavaScript script?

I want do banner - Hi (mail of user actually log in), Welcome back and insert it to all my HTML sites.

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at this [code in github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Web).
About your example, I think that the problem is with `onAuthStateChanged` method (user has logged out, so the auth state has changed, so it's triggered...).
Try to use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` what is explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword).

*By other way, separated question I would, [first make a search in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get%20user%20email%20firebase), and then, if no answered meets my needs, I would asked it in a new one!*

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Firebase but firebase.auth().signOut() should do the trick for you 
And in-order to identify if the user is logged in you can use the `onAuthStateChanged` event. If the passed parameter is null which means user is logged out if you have a valid value then you can resolve the user from that

ex: (I have not tried this but this should work)

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
        console.log('User Logged in :' + user );
        window.location.href ='event_list.html'
    }else{
        console.log('User Not Logged in');
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }
});

btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e => {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
});
```

Comment: @lucky44 are you using signInWithEmailAndPassword ?